# Hyundai battery drain

Tags: hyundai, wiring, battery-drain

My car battery drain i checked all the fuses with series connection of ammeter in battery negative always showing 0.85A what is the reason can any one please tell me. My car is HYNDAI I20 Magna 2012 model

Comment: If you remove each fuse one at a time, which causes the drain to stop?> What does that control?

Comment: I fix the issue my car break switch problem. Rectified